# Justify Text in TextView Android

Tags: android, textview

How do you get textview to be justified ? is it possible to get the solution? I have searched most of the forums but i didn't make it up. please help me out.

Comment: Here is an idea that should do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225353/text-justification-library-in-java/9755219#9755219

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android doesn't support text justification, sorry. You can use `android:gravity` attribute to align text to left or right or center etc, but you can't really justify it. The only option I guess is to use a `WebView` to show text and then use CSS to get the text justified.

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS text justification remains difficult too. Improving with latest specs, but there are still major issues such as Webkit not breaking long URLs.

Answer (score 15):

## UPDATED

We have created a simple class for this. There are currently two methods to achieve what you are looking for. Both require **NO WEBVIEW** and **SUPPORTS SPANNABLES**.

**LIBRARY**: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

**SUPPORTS**: Android 2.0 to 5.X

**SETUP**

```
// Please visit Github for latest setup instructions.
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image: Comparison.png]

Comment: I used this library but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @fargath: did u try this? ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText(input);
TextViewJustify.justifyText(((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview)), 305f); 
//Start from a small number like 150f and move up from there to get the exact width. 
//I haven't fixed this problem yet. 305f works best for me in this case.

Comment: library doesn't work properly

Comment: @Xylian Please open an issue in my github respository for this and then we can follow up there

Comment: @mk1 i posted an issue on the repo, when you put the TextViewEx inside a ScrollView, it cuts some of the text at the bottom, its like the scrollview cant calculate the height properly

Comment: @RonEskinder These issues have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="I'm TextView- Left" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="I'm TextView- Right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Hope this helps. If you have any difficulties write back.- Thanks

Comment: This works well so long as you don't have too many columns to handle.

Comment: This is not text justification, only a work-around when you have multiple columns. How about one column, though?

Comment: What do you want to explain here. Please tell any solution for text justification in android without using webView.