# Text justification library in Java

Tags: java, android, text-justify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i set property of Textview like justify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976627/can-i-set-property-of-textview-like-justify)

I'm writing an android app which needs text justification, which isn't supported natively, and I don't think using a WebView is going to work because of font and text sizes in relation to screen resolution and dimensions.  With this in mind I'm going to write a custom view which extends the TextView which will do text justification and was wondering if anybody knows of any code I can look at which does this already to save me some time. Any other helpful advice would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: Depeding on what kind of justification we're talking about - you can manage quite a lot by just using the `android:gravity` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately I need full text justification with hyphening, if possible.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## UPDATED

We have created a simple class for this. There are currently two methods to achieve what you are looking for. Both require **NO WEBVIEW** and **SUPPORTS SPANNABLES**.

**LIBRARY**: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

**SUPPORTS**: Android 2.X to 5.X

**SETUP**

```
// Please visit Github for latest setup instructions.
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image: Comparison.png]

Comment: and the origWidth argument would be relative to? :)

Comment: Good question. Well its been a while since I looked at it. Let me see what I can explain to you though. So when I initally wrote this, I thought that the characterWidth*numberofcharacters=width. But for some unknown reason, that is NOT true. It is infact characterWidth*numberofcharacters+[X]=width in which I don't know what [X] is. But I know that there is no direct correlation between [X] and the width. I will leave it to you to get this answer :D Please edit my response if you find out.

Comment: The reason is because the characters have varying width. For example, with some fonts the ! symbol is slimmer than the @ symbol. If you want to have characterWidth*numberofcharacters=width, then you'd need a fixed-width font. If you're not convinced, look at a fixed-width font. You'll see that the ! character has space to the left and right of it, while the @ symbol does not.