# Text justification in textview

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I have read through different questions and am now sure that full justtification is not supported by the textview in android. I don't want to use a webview because of decrease in performance.It will make the application too heavy for my liking. Recently I came across an algorithm for justification of text :

https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse221/200910/Projects/Markov/justification.html

I wanted to know if anyone implemented this program? If so, does it gives a better performance than what a webview wil give?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 0):

For TextView Justification, there is a library.You can use that.

Hope it might help you. [Text justification library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225353/text-justification-library-in-java/9755219#9755219)