# Pocket-like TextView automatic spacing based on TextView width?

Tags: android, textview

This is quite hard to understand, but I'm trying to find out how to make a `TextView` adapt to change the text spacing between words on a line which allows the text to reach the very right side of the TextView.

Consider this as an example (this should get my point across):

```
This one is a line of text which fills the view itself
This   is   another   that   does   the   same   thing
```

How would I go about making my text react like this? An example application which does this is Pocket, so I know it can be done - I just don't know how.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is called text [justification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_%28typesetting%29) and is something that has been discussed [more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20justify%20text) here on SO in the context of Android.

The short answer is that, unfortunately, justification is currently not (natively) supported by the `TextView` widget. There are however workarounds that involve either:

- Manipulating the text in the `TextView` in such a way that the result is visually close to that of justification. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225353/text-justification-library-in-java/9755219#9755219)
- Using a `WebView` to render the text. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922861/how-to-justify-text-on-a-textview-made-easy-android)

Justifying text on a web page is trivial, but the `WebView` is a more heavyweight component than a `TextView`, and hence the feature will come with a performance penalty.

Note that I don't know what approach Pocket is using for their articles, but there are ways to figure that out, and they're not too complicated. That's a completely different can of worms though, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Awesome, got it working. Question though; you say WebView is more heavyweight - so would it be possible to use a TextView and use `Html.fromHtml(text);`? Would that make a difference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Html.fromHtml(text)` will not get the job done because it'll break any justified formatting. [The number of supported html tags is limited](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) and any `style` attributes are most likely simply ignored when performing the conversion to a `Spanned`.