# How to justify text of TextView in Android

Tags: xml, textview

Hope you are doing well

I want to Justify my Text in `TextView`,

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible Duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225353/text-justification-library-in-java/9755219#9755219

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML Layout: declare WebView instead of TextView

```
<WebView
 android:id="@+id/textContent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java code: set text data to WebView

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.textContent);
String text;
text = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\">";
text+= "This is the text will be justified when displayed!!!";
text+= "</p></body></html>";
view.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This may Solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I use this project to justify text. It works fine with my projects. [JustifiedTextView](https://github.com/amilcar-sr/JustifiedTextView)

**XML code**

```
<com.codesgood.views.JustifiedTextView
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/card_use_hint"/>
```

**Result**

[Justified text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmCJJ.png)