# How to Justify the Text in TextView in Android

Tags: android

I want to Justify the text into textView. I does not want to use web view. because i can't increase the  text size at run time for different screens. So I want To use the text view. 
I want some things like that.[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text?rq=1

Comment: android doesn't support justification property and you may try
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366633/how-to-justify-text-of-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can set HTML on a TextView.

So...

```
String htmlString = "<p align=\"justify\">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>";
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

Good Luck. :)

Comment: The idea is about using HTML on TextView. I am not an HTML guy, so you have to make the HTML for yourself. o_O