# how to justify text in android textView using within xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

To justify text I have taked help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366633/how-to-justify-text-of-textview-in-android) please give me some way how to justify text in  android textView  within xml ?? thanx in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Justifying text inside a `TextView` is not actually fully supported in Android currently. You can see this from the duplicate question here:

[Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

There are some hack fixes to this, such as making the `TextView` a `WebView` and justifying the text with HTML but I would not recommend this. If it is essential for you to justify the text then I would suggest importing an external library that handles this.

Comment: thanx  for your feedback

Comment: @Hanan No problem. Hopefully one day it will be.