# How we get the text of a texview to be justified dynamically

Tags: android

In my application, I have an textview with many lines beside of product, but i need the data with proper appearance.Is it possible to have justified alignment dynamically?

Comment: Do you mean in a single textview, you want to align multiple lines separately?

Comment: Ya i have a single textview in that textview i have multiple lines, i want to justify that text properly. Now i am align the text either in right or left, center only but i want both side alignment that means justification.Thank you Kumar Bibek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android not supports full justification**

but check all answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922862/1168654) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291087/1168654).

Comment: Really its not support full justification ?

Comment: Solution https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
   TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setWidth(45);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // attempt at justifying text 
    tv.setMaxLines(1);
    tv.setText("Hellow");

    this.addView(tv);
```

but may Android not supports full justification.

Comment: Thank you ankitmakwana but my text came from webservice