# How to justify the description in single textview

Tags: android

In my application, I have an `TextView` with many lines beside of product, but I need the data with proper appearance.Is it possible to have justified alignment dynamically?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894704/1168654

Comment: [Android – How to display information with justify alignment?](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-how-to-display-information-with-justify-alignment/)

Comment: no you can not justify the text inside a textview. you can try with Hmtl.format()

Comment: Thank you Paresh Mayani, In the above link static text mentioned but my text dynamic text then how it is possible

Answer (score 1):

you can align your text dynamically some how as you want...

but, i guess there is no such facility available in android to fully justify text as the text editors does...

Comment: watch...stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text?rq=1

Comment: for this purpose some programmers also use web view...refer this...http://www.seal.io/2010/12/only-way-how-to-align-text-in-block-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Html Formatting in your textView like

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>Product Name</h1><br><p>Content</p>"));
```

Comment: I think question is **Is it possible to have justified alignment dynamically?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the instance of TextView on activity startup

```
TextView t = (TextView)FindViewById(R.id.TextView1)
t.setTextAppearance(context,parameter)
```

Comment: I think question is **Is it possible to have justified alignment dynamically?**

Comment: "but I need the data with proper appearance"  I considered this lines in the question