# Justify android text inside a listview without using a WebView

Tags: android, text, webview, justify

I need to justify a text in Android without using a WebView, because i use it inside a listview, that create a lot of problems because of the recycle, when i scroll down it's okay, but when i get back up, the webview keep the size of the last one, but change the text. That means that sometime i get a text with a lot of space, it disrupt my ListView.

Is there a library for that ?

Comment: Perhaps this could help you 
[how-can-i-set-property-of-textview-like-justify][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976627/can-i-set-property-of-textview-like-justify

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't justify text on TextView, but it seems that someone found a solution, by creating is own class/library.

Read carefully the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290877/justify-text-in-textview-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225353/text-justification-library-in-java/9755219#9755219). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Depends on how you want to justify the Text.

You could use

android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" //inside TextView

this will help the text right justified and there is also

```
android:gravity="right" // inside <TextView>
```

which will justify the text to right. Similarly `left` value will left justify.

Also Textview will have a default padding to support other language fonts.
Now you can disable this padding and justify the text further up by using

`setIncludeFontPadding`

Comment: but for the both sides, it's not possible ?

Comment: @Tsunaze no AFAIK it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**LIBRARY**: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

**SETUP**

```
// Please visit Github for latest setup instructions.
```

**COMPARISON**

[image: Comparison.png]